# Typescript does not allow to access a property dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some issues when I try to access  my object property in typescript:

```js
const total = (type: string) => {
  return {
    status: 'Total',
    test: data?[type].total,
  };
};

total('first')
```

This is how my data looks:

```js
data: {
  first: {
    total: 15
  },
  second: {
    total: 515
  }
}
```

Trying to access the property i get `TS2339: Property 'total' does not exist on type 'string[]'.` Why i get this and how to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you define any type property for data?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for for [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here and
`data?.[type]` is correct syntax.

Also TS will throw an error if just try to read object field with `object[property]`. It assumes correctly that it's not possible to read object property with just any `string`, it requires more specifics types. Have a look at code below.

```
interface Data {
  first: {
    total: number
  },
  second: {
    total: number
  }
}

const data: Data = {
  first: {
    total: 15
  },
  second: {
    total: 515
  }
}

const total = (type: keyof Data) => {
  return {
    status: 'Total',
    test: data?.[type].total
  }
}

total('first')
```

[Working snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA3gKGcmYKAZzAC5ld98wB7TAGwpAFcBbAI2j2QF8AaHsQgJaIACYUq1Oo2bsuUHrxwqcokKWTiMcCukzIAvJR6ES5U9WSy4TZAEYArMsH5hGyVZn07FJ87KqjjqYlq2DPgmABRgAJ4ADhBkANYQcbQwaLoAlMYAfN7WUBBgLFAgRdbIpBgsxBQA5AAqvgyNbtU0EKQUOpgA-AB0ANrxSQC6QxE81rzIs3whEdGN5qSNOUA)